# Main.c:3:9: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token

Tags: c

In this simple program to find whether a number is even or odd it keeps howing the error Main.c:3:9: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘{’ token. Please help.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main{
int n;
  scanf("%d",&n);

  if(n%2==0)
    printf("%d is an even number",n);

  else
    printf("%d is an odd number",n);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You forgot the `()` after `main`

Comment: Oh. Thank you! Totally forgot that

Comment: @litelite: That would better be `(void)`; an empty parameter-list is an obsolecence feature; don't use it anymore!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you left off the `()` when declaring `main`, the compiler thinks you are declaring a variable, hence the confusion expressed in the error message.

Comment: The recommended signature for a function witrhout arguments is to use prototype syntax, i.e. `int main(void)`. An empty parameter list is an obsolecence feature and to be removed in a future version of the standard.